# API gateway No integration defined for method

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

"No integration defined for method" when trying to Deploy (this particular API) . Here are the steps that I have done:

1. I defined HTTP Headers under "Method Request".
2. I defined "Integration Request" pointing to my lambda function.
3. defined "Method Response"
4. defined "Integration Response".
5. I tested with sample data and confirmed that my lambda function was called via my API correctly. The logging in Cloudwatch also confirm a successful test.
6. Now, when I tried to "Deploy" with either an existing stage or new stage, it keeps saying "No integration defined for method".

I followed through all the steps from AWS tutorial on how to setup API Gateway. And, this is not the only API I have done. I have successfully created and deployed a few other APIs under this same account using the same steps. Other APIs are deployed without any issues. I use basically the same steps and settings for this API as in other but, I have no idea why this particular API return error "No integration defined for method" when I try to deploy it. I even deleted the API and recreated it but still having the same error.